# Selecting j students at random

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A and B are in a class of n students. A group of j students is selected from the class at random. Find the probabilities that

(i) neither A nor B are in the group;

(ii) A and B are both in the group;

(iii) A is in the group but B is not.

My solution:
Denominator will be $(_nC_j)$
Numerators:
$(1) _{n-2}C_j$
$(2)_{n-2}C_{j-2}$
$(3)_{n-1}C_{j-1}$

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the (iii) part, we have to choose A to be in and make sure that B is not in.

Hence, we need to choose $j-1$  studdents from the remaining $n-2$ students (that is to exclude student B as well)

Comment: ya right. Thanks